# <canvas> for chartjs versus AMP

Tags: javascript, amp, canvas

On my WordPress blog in default mode I have a `<canvas>` where I draw a chart with ChartJS. I've just downloaded the AMP plugin, run the Google AMP Test tool, and it says:

> Fix the following issue
>   Prohibited or invalid use of HTML Tag
>   The tag 'canvas' is disallowed.

How do you go about fixing this? Is there any way to do JavaScript with AMP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run your own JavaScript when using AMP, that defeats the purpose of AMP. Instead, you can iframe your external content using the [amp-iframe element](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-iframe).

1. Add the amp-iframe JS to the head.

   ```html
   <script async custom-element="amp-iframe"
     src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-iframe-0.1.js"></script>
   ```
2. Add the amp-iframe element where you want your iframe to go.

   ```html
   <amp-iframe width="200" height="100"
     sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" layout="responsive"
     src="https://example.com/"></amp-iframe>
   ```

A full guide to using amp-iframe is available at:

- https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/iframes

Comment: AMP sounds awful.

Comment: Unfortunately, my blog does not support `https`, which Google requires for AMP, but fortunately my chart is inserted via a custom `[graph]` tag, and it has fallback functionality for `<noscript>` and sharing tools, so I've tweaked the code to always output the static JPG (drawn using an ancient PHP library) when rendering to AMP, so now we cleanly pass the Google check.